# How to use oauth2 to get a token in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, api, rest

i work with VB.net in my job and we have a API to comunicate with a marketplace. But 1 week ago, they changed authentication mode (Basic to oAuth2). I don't have experience creating API rest, and can't improve this, cause i don't understand how.[The first image show the old type of communication, not working anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrD1T.png)
For newer communication, the plataform give us a API Key, IDkey, Secret Key, and Tenant ID key, and i don't now, how to use it. Anyone can help me with a example ?

This is the actual code

```
        Dim webRequest__1 As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(URLAuth), HttpWebRequest)
        webRequest__1.Method = "POST"
        webRequest__1.Accept = "application/json"
        webRequest__1.ContentType = "application/json"

        webRequest__1.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache")
        webRequest__1.Headers.Add("Authorization", {Table With key})

        Dim putString As String = "{"
        putString += "      ""Format"": " & """" & "zpl" & """" & ","
        putString += "      ""Orders"": " & "[" & """" & local.text & """" & "]"
        putString += "}"

        Dim requestWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(webRequest__1.GetRequestStream())
        requestWriter.Write(putString)
        requestWriter.Close()

        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
        postresponse = TryCast(webRequest__1.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim resposta As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd
        TxtRespostaApi.Text = resposta
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow?force_isolation=true

Comment: While OAuth2 is pretty much a standard, in practice I've found there are subtle differences in the exact usages from implementation to implementation depending on grant types etc.  Generally speaking, the API developers will publish a guide on how they expect it to work.  It's also not uncommon for developers to publish wrappers (often as nugets) that do a lot of the work for you.